# Smallest possible PCB size for TI CC3200

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-assembly, texas-instruments

I'm just getting started with hardware side of Computers. At this point, I'm really interested in TI's CC3200 Network Processor, which has an integrated CPU to allow me to run custom code. You can see the datasheet here: [enter link description here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc3200.pdf).

Since I'm a hardware noob, to me it looks like this SoC is pretty much self-contained and that if I just powered the chip it will work, but I'm also thinking that it probably requires more components. Can anyone look at the datasheet and quickly tell me what's the smallest pcb size you think is required for this chip, assuming I only need to power this chip and don't need to connect any LEDs etc.

Comment: It will be helpful if people down voting provided a reason as well. I already mentioned that I'm new to this, so maybe I'm asking something that's obvious to the knowledgeable folks here, but not to me.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because of your request for someone to read the datasheet for you. Reviewing a datasheet for as complex a device as a WLAN microcontroller, to determine a minimal bill of materials and possible layouts, is a non-trivial task, it is what many EEs do as part of their jobs and get paid for. This question might get better tolerance on the TI official site, to be honest. Finally, no, the CC3200 will not work simply by powering it - At the very least, clock sources, decoupling capacitors and some form of antenna would be needed. See Fig 3-2 for an apparent minimal layout.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Thank you! I found the TI forum for this device at: http://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/968.aspx I will re-post my question there.

Comment: @IceCreamMan, even there it is preferred if only a small percentage of the questions you have can be answered with "see page *x*".

Comment: @IceCreamMan I voted to close this question because the only correct answer would take literally hours of work and might still be open to opinion i.e. this question is not appropriate for this site. And, even if you got a couple of guys to agree on an answer, how would you (or anyone) judge that it is the absolutely correct answer?

Comment: The datasheet itself links you to the layout app note http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru370/swru370.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to start getting your hands dirty with this kind of thing is to buy an evaluation board from the chip vendor.
TI seems to call these 'launchpads' and you're in luck, as they have [such a board for a CC3200](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-connected-cc3200-launchxl.html) for only 30 bucks.